# How to use Chef PHP cookbook to install version higher than 5.3.3

Tags: php, centos, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using the Opscode community PHP cookbook to install PHP on a node.  The node is CentOS and I have attempted setting the install_method to "source" and also tried overriding the version in my Role file.

No matter what I do - Chef continues to install PHP 5.3.3.

I want to know how to use this cookbook to install a newer version of PHP - or understand if it's even possible.  I see references to PHP 5.3.28 and 5.4.15 in the default attribute settings - so I am under the impression that it should be possible.

Does anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Why is this question closed as off-topic? DevOps is programming honestly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef simply uses the packages available in the systems package repositories. So that might be 5.3 in your case.

The reference to 5.4.15 is for the source install. You'd have to use another recipe

```
php::source
```

You could set the preferred version for PHP from chef

```
:php => {
  :version => "5.5",
},
```

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the reply.  I have attempted this method and for some reason I am still left with PHP 5.3.3 on RHEL6.  I included only the "php::source" recipe in my run list and added the php version to my "default_attributes" in the run list as well.  I am running an application specific cookbook that includes the php cookbook, discovers and updates the PEAR repo, and installs some additional packages such as php-mbstring, php-pdo, and php-pdo_mysql.  Not sure if that has something to do with it - I'll attempt to leave those out on a run and see what happens...

Comment: Gosh - ran only the php::source reciepe on a clean instance.  Removed anything else - straight out of the box.  It goes through all of the php extensions listed in the source recipe - then runs php::package.  Super confused - I don't see any code in the php:source recipe that refers to php:package.  Am I totally missing something?  php::package
  * package[php] action install (up to date)
  * package[php-devel] action install
    - install version 5.3.3-27.el6_5 of package php-devel

Comment: I don't hav emuch texperience using the source install with chef. So you probably have to write a chef recipe for installing a repo in RHEL that support  PHP 5.5. And update the php recipe to install 5.5 for RHEL.

Comment: So - I managed to get this to work by moving the PHP cookbook before the Apache cookbook in my run list.  If I include the Apache::mod_php5 recipe it will install the php53 package on RHEL family platforms if it does not find that PHP has already been installed.  However - I then continued to run into an issue with libphp5.so file not being added to the Apache install when installing PHP from source.

Comment: Do you still install apache2-php5 after installing PHP?