# Chef PHP Cookbook install 5.5 package or source

Tags: php, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to Chef. I'm using the [Chef PHP Cookbook](http://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/php) to install PHP. Using the default setting it installs version `5.4.16`.

I overrode the following:

```
default['php']['install_method'] = 'source'
default['php']['version'] = '5.5.38'
default['php']['checksum'] = '4f458c9b504269615715a62f182b7c2f89bb8284f484befc221b56a1571b506e'
```

**Note**: checksum I found at [the download page](https://secure.php.net/downloads.php), it's the `sha256` value.

Considering **I need PHP 5.5, not specifically 5.5.38**, is installing from source the correct approach, or is there a preferred method and source is for specific versions?

Comment: I think that the default method is `package`, right?

Comment: Correct. If I don't override those 3 attributes, it defaults to `package` and installs the 5.4.

Comment: I think that what you did is the right way...based on the info of the site(https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/php), on the `Recipes` item, they say that source is for install php from source...also you can follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132353/how-to-use-chef-php-cookbook-to-install-version-higher-than-5-3-3

Comment: Do you have an actual Chef problem or are you just stating what you did?

Comment: @coderanger I'm asking whether the PHP cookbook can install PHP 5.5, other than directly compiling it from source.

Comment: Sure, if you have a packaged version of 5.5 from somewhere matching how the normal system packages work, it can install that.